How do I get a field definition with an open generic return type from a closed generic type definition?
I'm currently making a small toy compiler for a .NET language. Right now I want to implement tuple comparison. This is what the C# compiler generates:
...
IL_0019: ldloc.3
IL_001a: ldfld !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.ValueTuple`3<int32, int32, int32>::Item1
IL_001f: ldloc.s 4
IL_0021: ldfld !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.ValueTuple`3<int32, int32, int32>::Item1
IL_0026: bne.un.s IL_0048
...

As you can see in line 2 (label IL_001a), the ldfld instruction loads a field from the constructed generic type System.ValueTuple`3<int32, int32, int32>, but the return type is still !0, and not int32.
Currently, I'm using the following simple code, where tupleType is a constructed generic type, like above.
foreach (FieldInfo field in tupleType.GetFields())
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, tuple1Index);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, tuple2Index);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);

    ...
}

The issue is, the compiler yields the following IL instead:
ldfld int32 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`3<int32,int32,int32>::Item1

Where the field type is int32 instead of the type parameter !0. This results in the following exception being thrown when the assembly is executed:
Unhandled exception. System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'System.ValueTuple`3.Item1'.
   at Program.Main(String[])

I also tried using the open generic type using Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), but this also does not work, as the type arguments are - obviously - not filled in.
How can I retrieve a field from a constructed generic type whose return type in the IL remains a type argument instead of a filled in type?

Can you provide a complete reproduceable example? For me foreach(var field in typeof(ValueTuple<int, int, int>).GetFields()) il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field); produces ldfld !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.ValueTuple'3<int32,int32,int32>::Item1 instructions.

Ok, that's actually very interesting. I just tried your exact code and on .NET 4.8.1 it produces the correct output (the one you got). When using the same exact code on .NET 9 though (which I did in the OP) [you need to change AssemblyBuilder to PersistedAssemblyBuilder for it to work], I get the output I described in the OP.

Here's my full code: https://pastebin.com/DjjFgrsW

Indeed I tested with the old .NET to simply dump the dynamic assembly. I would expect the same behaviour in all versions.

@Jonas_ how did you save if you did not use the PersistedAssemblyBuilder?

@IvanPetrov My code should compile as is. On .NET Framework PersistedAssemblyBuilder does not exist and you can save assemblies generated by the normal one. For the .NET 9 example I did indeed use PersistedAssemblyBuilder.

@Jonas_ so the pastebin under .NET9 reproduces your issue?

@IvanPetrov Yes.

Looks like a bug. PersistedAssemblyBuilder being a new API for the persistence in .NET 9 makes it not entirely unlikely:

This implementation has no dependency on the pre-existing,
runtime-specific Reflection.Emit implementation.

In the metadata blob the signature that is referenced in the MemberRef (0A table), is "wrong" or not according to spec.
For .NET Framework dynamic IL case (and all other C# compilers I could find) it's supposed to be:
- 06-13-00 
- 06-13-01
- 06-13-02

See example under VI.B.4.3 Metadata from ECMA-335 (6th edition):

class Phone<K,V> { 
 private V[] vals; 
} 

Similarly, the signature for the field vals is encoded as:
0x06 FIELD 
0x1D ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY 
0x13 ELEMENT_TYPE_VAR 
0x01 1, representing generic argument number 1 (i.e., “V”)


under .NET 9.0's new API it's just:
- 06-08

Instead of ELEMENT_TYPE_VAR (0x13) for generic and the generic argument number (0,1,2), the type 08 which is int32 is directly appended for the type of the field.
This is what we see in ILSpy's output: !0,!1,!2 vs int32:
ldfld !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.ValueTuple`3<int32, int32, int32>::Item1
ldfld int32 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.ValueTuple`3<int32,int32,int32>::Item1

So I guess the possibly invalid metadata causes the runtime exception you are experiencing.
